# How can i make that the files extensions selection will be for lower cases and upper cases?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

                string dir = this.folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                var extensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                images = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(fileName => extensions.Any(extension => fileName.EndsWith(extension))).ToArray();
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(images);
                if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    beginConvertionToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now it's only for .jpg .gif .png lower cases how can i make that it will be also for upper cases JPG GIF PNG without adding the extensions again as upper cases manualy ?

Comment: Perhaps use the overload for `EndsWith` that accepts `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`?

Comment: You should really be using `Path.GetExtension` for this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx) with the overload `StringComparison`, for example `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. I would also use the [`System.IO.Path` class:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var images = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fileName => extensions
        .Any(extension => extension.Equals(
            Path.GetExtension(fileName), 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    .ToArray();
```

If `extension` could be `null` i'd prefer `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals`:

```
var images = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fileName => extensions
        .Any(extension => StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(
            Path.GetExtension(fileName),
            extension)))
    .ToArray();
```

But instead of `Enumerable.Any` you could also use `Enumerable.Contains` directly:

```
var images = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fileName => extensions
        .Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice code, but a guy with only 21 points to their name might have a hard time explaining how he solved his homework problem with this version. :)